# Selecting random data in SQL and R

Tags: r, random, microsoft-r

I have this SQL-Server code: `ABS(checksum(newid())%14`

that generates uniformally distributed random numbers between 0 and 13.

More specifically, I have a column in my SQL table that has these random numbers. Doing some analysis in R, I have now imported this SQL table into R using Microsoft-R / XDF file. I would like to create a test and training set on 80%-20% of this data based on this column. Do you know how I would do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I edited my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this manually with two `rxDataStep`s:

```
train <- rxDataStep(infile, "train.xdf", rowSelection=random_number < 11)
test <- rxDataStep(infile, "test.xdf", rowSelection=random_number >= 11)
```

where the cutoff is 0.8*13. If you'll be doing a lot of data munging with Xdf files, consider installing [dplyrXdf](https://github.com/revolutionAnalytics/dplyrXdf). It lets you use dplyr verbs and pipelines, treating Xdfs as if they were data frames. You can get it with

```
devtools::install_github("revolutionAnalytics/dplyrXdf")
```

The above code would become

```
train <- filter(infile, random_number < 11, .outFile="train.xdf")
test <- filter(infile, random_number >= 11, .outFile="test.xdf")
```

Alternatively, you can create a factor variable from your input, and call `rxSplit` on that:

```
rxDataStep(infile, infile,
    transforms=list(splitVar=factor(random_number < 11, levels=c("train", "test")))
lst <- rxSplit(infile, splitByFactor="splitVar")
```

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE:***
Since its an .XDF file, I would use the the `rxSplitXdf` function.
Here is an article that discusses it in depth and shows examples:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/r-server/r-reference/revoscaler/rxsplitxdf

Something like:

```
rxSplitXdf(inFile, outFileSuffixes = c("train","test"),  
         numOutFiles = 2, splitBy = "rows", 
         rowSelection = (random number >=7))
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that this dataset is huge, it is not stored as a dataframe, rather it is an XDF file. So, it can only be partitioned by this random number.

Comment: Ahh. Okay, that is very helpful, thanks! But, I just put the random_number >=7 argument in there, but I'm not sure this will do it in the 80-20 split as required. Is there anyway to accomplish the 80-20 split?

Comment: This doesn't work as you think it does. The `rowSelection` arg filters _all_ the rows in the dataset before partitioning, so the total no. of rows in the output files will be half that of the input.